# Navigating around website with firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

this question might seem simple but I am trying to find a way to navigate around my website which I'm hosting on firebase host.

so I've created this website with this screen
[image]

now when the user clicks on the "living room" option in the toolbar I want to navigate them to the living room screen, I looked around I read on the firebase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) that I can redirect users to other pages of my website using rewrites

so I tried to change the URL when the user clicks on the living room option to

"myAppDomain/LivingRoom"

and then I fixed the firebase.js file and added this to it

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "/LivingRoom",
  "destination": "/LivingRoom.html"
} ],
```

so for now when the user clicks on a button I just change his URL to "myWebSiteDomain.com/LivingRoom". sadly it doesn't seem to work for me.

I just want to direct users to other screens when they request it. How can achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Rewrites are for changing the URL of a certain page. Not moving the user to a different page. What your rewrite did, is it changed the URL from yoursite.com/LivingRoom.html to yoursite.com/LivingRoom If your navigation bar uses the button tag , add the onclick attribute and use window.location.href to redirect the user.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = "LivingRoom.html">Living Room</button>
```

If your site uses link tags  for the navigation, add the href attribute.

```
<a href="LivingRoom.html">Living Room</a>
```